# AS3: use buttons in external swf

Tags: actionscript-3, button, flash, external

I am making a website in Adobe Flash that imports it´s navigation buttons from an external swf-file.
The problem is how my Main FLA-file will know which of the navigation buttons the users has pressed, since the buttons and it's eventListeners are in the external swf-file.

With other word: can I make my external swf-file return a Number to my website FLA-file, to determine which button that have been pressed? If so, how?

Comment: Would you like to go down the path of php and loading url request, or would you want to create a local connection between the two swfs to send and receive data? I have done this kind of website before so I can potentially help you with this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to answer. I wish to build my website only in Adobe Flash and not use PHP.

Comment: Does the answer help you? I have another solution if you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a connection between the external swf and main swf using the `LocalConnection()`

In main.swf

```
var sending_lc:LocalConnection;
sending_lc = new LocalConnection();

function send_it(evt:MouseEvent):void 
{
    sending_lc.send("connectionName", "functionName", "myData");
    //params are (connection name, function to execute in the receiving swf, the data to pass through)
}

my_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, send_it);
```

In exetrnal.swf

```
var receiving_lc:LocalConnection;
receiving_lc = new LocalConnection();

receiving_lc.connect("connectionName");
receiving_lc.client = this;

function functionName(data:String):void {
trace(data);
}
```

Comment: I will try it. I have to change it a bit though since I want to send a value from the external swf (when clicked on a button) to the main.swf.